# How to include .equals in Angular parameters from URL?

Tags: angular

I need to make a request like this:

```
http://localhost:9000/api/follows?followedId.equals=1
```

But when I do this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/follows']" [queryParams]="{ followedId.equals: profile.id }">Following</a>
```

It breaks. It works without the .equals but I need it and I do not know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: A dot is not valid as part of the key for an object. You can try with `{ ["followedId.equals"]: profile.id }` but I'm not sure if it would work. What do you need the query params string to look like?

Comment: No, it does not and I can not find how to scape the point

Answer (score 0):

Define the query string object within your ts file, like so:

```
 params = { ["followedId.equals"]: this.profile.id }
```

And then use that object within your template, like so:

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/follows']" [queryParams]="params">Following</a>
```